# Java switch case always runs default code

Tags: java, switch-statement

The switch case always runs the default code. I read something about a "new line" issue, but i think that is not the case here. Because i copy the first char from the "stringclient" string into a char variable. But when i run this with my ATMServer class in eclpise, it's working just fine. Only when i execute them from cmd, this problem appears. So anyone knows what's going on? Please help. Thanks.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ATMClient {

    private static final int PORT = 20000;

    private static final char DRAW_STR = 'Α';
    private static final char DEPOSIT_STR = 'Κ';
    private static final char BALANCE_STR = 'Υ';
    private static final char EXIT_STR = 'Ε';

    private static boolean hasEnded = false;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Socket dataSocket = new Socket("localhost",PORT);
        InputStream is = dataSocket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        OutputStream os = dataSocket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(os, true);


        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String stringclient;

        while(!hasEnded){
            printMenu();

            stringclient = input.readLine();

            char optionCode = stringclient.charAt(0);
            String tempData;
            int amount;

            switch(optionCode){
            case EXIT_STR:
                out.println(String.valueOf(EXIT_STR));
                hasEnded = true;
                continue;
            case DRAW_STR:
                tempData = stringclient.substring(1);

                try{
                    amount = Integer.parseInt(tempData);
                }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    System.out.println("Το ποσό πρέπει να είναι αριθμός. Δοκιμάστε ξανά.");
                    System.out.println();
                    continue;
                }

                if(amount > 420){
                    System.out.println("Μπορείτε να κάνετε ανάληψη έως 420 ευρώ.");
                    System.out.println();
                    continue;
                }

                out.println(String.valueOf(DRAW_STR) + amount);
                break;

            case DEPOSIT_STR:
                tempData = stringclient.substring(1);

                try{
                    amount = Integer.parseInt(tempData);
                }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    System.out.println("Το ποσό πρέπει να είναι αριθμός. Δοκιμάστε ξανά.");
                    System.out.println();
                    continue;
                }

                out.println(String.valueOf(DEPOSIT_STR) + amount);

                break;

            case BALANCE_STR:
                out.println(String.valueOf(BALANCE_STR));
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Λάθος επιλογή. Δοκιμάστε ξανά.");
                System.out.println();
                continue;
            }

            String reply = in.readLine();

            System.out.println(reply);
        }

        out.close();
        os.close();
        in.close();
        is.close();
        input.close();
        dataSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should log what the character.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with the  character encoding of the source file. Try compiling with the 'javac -encoding'. Also, I think when you run from Eclipse, it takes care of the character encoding when you run the application and input your value, where as with cmd, when you input your value it uses your default system encoding and that's why there is this inconsistency; only a guess though.

Comment: No change. It still works in eclpise, but in cmd it doesn't. I don't get it how it works in eclpise though.

Comment: Can you try this: BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

Comment: Nope. Still nothing. But when i replaced the "optionCode" variable inside the switch expression with 'Α'  it run the DRAW_STR case normally. It seems that when the switch expression is not a variable it works.

Comment: How are you running your app in "cmd"? are you using command line to execute your class?

Comment: Yes. It's a simple cmd program, some programming homework. It's like an echo client-server, "simulating" an ATM.

Comment: try compiling with and without encoding option e.g. javac -encoding UTF-8 ATMClient.java. if you first try javac ATMClient.java, see if you get any errors.

Comment: I found a solution. I used println to see the numerical codes of the four greek constant chars i use in the program and then i assigned those codes in the char constants. Now it's working. But i don't know if this is going to work on another pc with different encodings though.

Comment: lol wouldn't call it a solution. more like a "hack". But if you are happy :)

Comment: Well solution hack whatever. It works and that's what matters. But will this still work in another pc with different encoding? My professor's pc runs linux and i think linux has different encoding. I had some small encoding issues with some previous homework.

Comment: Well if you have "lucky/hacky" solutions thats what will happen. Back to your question, i am not sure. I would suggest compiling your source using the -encoding option and trying it out. I think in cmd its using your local machine encoding,which is different from Eclipses thats why there is inconsistency.

Comment: Ok i will try the -encoding option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with final `char` constants. Just tried debugging the code and it it returned ASCII value 913 for `DRAW_STR` constant, which is character `\u0391` in Java (i.e. Greek Alpha).

So, let's say, when user inputs 'A(150)', A has 65 `ASCII` value whereas `DRAW_STR` has 913 `ASCII` value and hence, they do not match and control goes to `default` block. The reason it works in eclipse can be the character set used by eclipse.

I fixed it by removing that character and re-typing again. It seems it may have been because of copy paste. However, if you want to remove that possibility then you can use `unicode` representations of chatacters (e.g. `private static final char DRAW_STR = '\u0041';`). [Here](http://unicode-table.com/en/#0041) is the unicode character table.

Comment: It's not working. And besides the "stringclient" string is user input and i always type that with capitals.

Comment: What is the user input provided to this program?

Comment: This program simulates an ATM. The user input is 'Α(ammount)' to draw money, 'Κ(ammount)' to deposit, 'Υ' to show the balance and 'Ε' to exit. (Those Α,Κ,Υ,Ε are greek letters). For example, when i type 'Α150', it means draw 150 ammount of money. The default in switch is for anything else the user types and shows an error message to the user.

Comment: When i run this in eclipse it works fine. But from cmd yes, it doesn't work in any case. It always runs default and prints my error message.

Comment: I didn't copy those greek characters. I typed them from the keyboard (my keyboard has greek layout too). And at the user input i type Α150 with greek alpha, so how the ascii code is 65 when i type with greek layout?

Comment: Just try printing value of character i.e. `System.out.println((int)optionCode);`

Comment: So i used println and for greek alpha i get 8364. I also printed the other three chars as well and then i assigned those code numbers in the char variables and now it finally works

Answer (score 0):

I found a 'solution'. I used System.out.println(); to print the numerical codes of the four greek constants i use in the program. Then i assigned those numbers to the char constants instead of the characters and it worked.